# postgresql.conf max_prepared_transactions doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, transactions, prepare

I opened up my postgresql.conf file in the postgres data folder and changed the value of max_prepared_connections to a non-zero value.

However, every time I try using a "PREPARE TRANSACTION 'foo';"command, I get an error saying that max_prepared_connections is set to zero.

Am I doing anything wrong?  I just want to be able to use the prepare transaction command.

Comment: try to recheck max_prepared_connections before using PREPARE TRANSACTION - try to execute:  show max_prepared_transactions; sometimes people editing other config file that is used

Answer (score 6):

You must restart the PosgreSQL server after changing this parameter.

Answer (score 3):

go to place where postgresql is installed... in windows , go to
    C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\postgresql.conf
    open and then search for "max_prepared_transactions" and uncomment it.
    and then set max_prepared_transactions = 1
 zero disables the feature
 (change requires restart)
Note:  Increasing max_prepared_transactions costs ~600 bytes of shared memory
per transaction slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).
It is not advisable to set max_prepared_transactions nonzero unless you
actively intend to use prepared transactions.

after that type services in start menu and search for postgresql and stop the service from left top corner. then restart this service.
then restart the jboss server .

Answer (score 3):

1. Run following Query e.g. ALTER SYSTEM SET max_prepared_transactions = 100;
2. Restart Service
3. Validate by running following Query :- SHOW max_prepared_transactions;

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that there can be a file `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\share\postgresql.conf.sample` which has the same structure as `Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\postgresql.conf`. So, you should also change `max_prepared_transactions` in that file.

Comment: Can you say why this is needed? The file sounds like a installation sample which is not used at runtime.